# Array copy will not work in a if statement or by button click sub

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a small log ( string array of 10  ) of time stamps that on a event will move the newest event towards the first string in the array.
  Here is a few attempts that I have tried.  The only time the array will change is when it is in a timer.

What Iam looking to do is 
on a bit change to copy arrayA(1) to array(0). witch will move the string from (1) to (0),(2) to (1),(3) to (2) and the rest of the array.   So when the event happens it cascades the strings to make a list of last events (0) would be the 10th event that happened and the (9) would be the first or latest event
                      Attempt 1

```
Private Sub RcvTmr_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RcvTmr.Tick

dim SrvUpTimeStgArray(9) as string
If BtnBit = False And OneShot(5) = True Then

        OneShot(5) = False
        SrvUpTimeStgArray(9) = LAtimeSvrUp.TimeString
        For I = 0 To 8
            SrvUpTimeStgArray(I) = SrvUpTimeStgArray(I + 1)
        Next
        LAtimeSvrUp.StopTimer()
    End If

    ListBox1.DataSource = SrvUpTimeStgArray
End Sub
```

Then this code to

```
Private Sub RcvTmr_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RcvTmr.Tick
Dim StringArrayA(9) as string : Dim StringArrayB(9) as string
If OneShot(10) = False Then
        OneShot(10) = True

        StringArrayA(3) = "testst 33333"
        StringArrayA(2) = "testst 22222"
        StringArrayA(1) = "testst 11111"
        StringArrayA(0) = "testst 00000"
    End If
    StringArrayA(0) = StringArrayA(1)
    If Btn1TestBit Then
        counter1 = counter1 + 1
        BtnTest3.Text = "worked"
        'Call ArrayCopy()
        Btn1TestBit = False
        StringArrayA(0) = StringArrayA(1)
' The below was alternated with the above line ans also did not work
        ' Array.Copy(StringArrayA, 1, StringArrayB, 0, 4)
    End If

    ListBox1.DataSource = StringArrayA
    ListBox2.DataSource = StringArrayB
    Lacount3.Text = counter1
End Sub
```

I am missing something so thanks..

Update but It has duplicate strings to the array
This is using the AddLog Sub

```
If ClientConnBit = False And OneShot(5) = True Then
        OneShot(5) = False
        AddLog(SrvUpTimeStgArray, "Stopped @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString() & "* Up Time " & LAtimeSvrUp.TimeString)
        LAtimeSvrUp.StopTimer()
        For Each entry As String In SrvUpTimeStgArray
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry) Then
                LBSvrUptimeLog.Items.Add(entry)
            End If
        Next
        'LBSvrUptimeLog.DataSource = SrvUpTimeStgArray
        My.Settings.UpTimeString.AddRange(SrvUpTimeStgArray)
        My.Settings.Save()

    End If
```

Comment: Which of the several arrays in your code are you having a problem with? What do Button.Click handlers or Timers have to do with this question? It would help if you could edit your question to show one section of code that doesn't do what you want, then explain what you want it to do and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the values backward, if you do it forward you'll end up copying the same value everywhere. I suggest you load how to use break point and watch.

This is how it would look like

```
Sub AddLog(ByVal logAsArray() As String, ByVal newEntry As String)

    For index As Integer = logAsArray.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
        logAsArray(index) = logAsArray(index - 1)
    Next

    logAsArray(0) = newEntry

End Sub
```

You can also use list instead

```
Sub AddLog(ByVal logAsList As List(Of String), ByVal newEntry As String)

    If logAsList.Count = logAsList.Capacity Then
        logAsList.RemoveAt(logAsList.Capacity - 1)
    End If

    logAsList.Insert(0, newEntry)

End Sub
```

Here's an example on how to use these functions.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim logAsArray(2) As String

    AddLog(logAsArray, "a")
    AddLog(logAsArray, "b")
    AddLog(logAsArray, "c")
    AddLog(logAsArray, DateTime.Now.ToString())

    For Each entry As String In logAsArray
        Console.WriteLine(entry)
    Next

    Dim logAsList As New List(Of String)(3)

    AddLog(logAsList, "a")
    AddLog(logAsList, "b")
    AddLog(logAsList, "c")
    AddLog(logAsList, DateTime.Now.ToString())

    For Each entry As String In logAsList
        Console.WriteLine(entry)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: Great @the_lotus  So how would I trigger this on an event like a if statement Inside of the timer Sub? I tried this
`code`
   If Btn1TestBit Then
            AddLog(StringArrayA, DateTime.Now.ToString())

            For Each entry As String In StringArrayA
                ListBox1.DataSource = entry
            Next
        End If

Comment: `If Btn1TestBit Then AddLog(StringArrayA, DateTime.Now.ToString()) For Each entry As String In StringArrayA ListBox1.DataSource = entry Next End If`

Comment: Still not sure how to implement this to work in my application? I have some of it working but I get repeat strings here and there/..
                            Posted to my main of what I have wrote so far..

Comment: @ms_ssccControls It hard to figure out what is hapenning, I think you have a different problem from the original question since I'm pretty sure your array is ok. Put a break point and see. From your updated code, I don't see anywhere where you clear up LBSvrUptimeLog, UpTimeString. Everytiem you insert all strings back into these list.